# how can i have links in my dropdown list?

Tags: html, css, list

The problem is I want to create dropdown menu for my site with link and that doesn't work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    a.mainhrf ul.mainul
    {
        display: none;
    }
    a.mainhrf:hover ul.mainul
    {
        display: block;
    }
    a.mainhrf ul.mainul li
    {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="mainhrf" href="#">Siemaza
        <ul class="mainul">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Without an `a` inside `li` its working

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    a.mainhrf ul.mainul
    {
        display: none;
    }
    a.mainhrf:hover ul.mainul
    {
        display: block;
    }
    a.mainhrf ul.mainul li
    {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="mainhrf" href="#">Siemaza
        <ul class="mainul">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

I will be really thankful if you'll help me! :)

Comment: Its very unclear as to what you're trying to achieve and what the problem is

Comment: This is why [the W3C HTML validator exists](https://validator.w3.org/) and should be used often.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're nesting `a` tags...

Switch the parent to a div and it works fine.

```css
.mainul {
  display: none;
}
.mainhrf:hover .mainul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainhrf">Siemaza
  <ul class="mainul">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vvub9wnj/

Comment: If you want to keep the link on the parent element, wrap it around the text only and keep it in a `div`  

`<div class="mainhrf"><a href="#">Siemaza</a> ... </div>`